# How to execute function immediately?

Tags: jquery

I have 10 functions:

```
$("#one").mouseenter(function(){
$('#two,#three,#four,#five').fadeTo(700,0.2);
});
$("#one").mouseleave(function(){
$('#two,#three,#four,#five').fadeTo(700,1);
});


$("#two").mouseenter(function(){
$('#one,#three,#four,#five').fadeTo(700,0.2);
});
$("#two").mouseleave(function(){
$('#one,#three,#four,#five').fadeTo(700,1);
});
```

etc...

how do I make each function act immediately? At the moment they wait for the function to finish before starting the next one. Which causes [chaos](http://tragicclothing.co.uk/index%202.html) if you go from div one to div two before the function has finished (for example).

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#one").stop().fadeTo()
```

[Documentation for `.stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), which halts any current animation.

I might also suggest that you use classes:

```
$(".thing").mouseenter(function () {
   $(".thing").not(this).stop().fadeTo(700, 0.2);
});
```