# jQuery animate({textIndent})

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have this snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".sidebar .nav li a.animate").hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({textIndent:"133"}, "fast")
}, function(){
    $(this).animate({textIndent:"27"}, "fast")
});
});
```

Basically it's an animation for the items of the menu. It works properly, but if you pass the mouse from top to bottom and reverse multiple times, you can notice a nasty delay with the animations still going.

How can I prevent this from happening? Should I block the event after it has been triggered? What's the best way to solve this? :)

Code examples are appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute function immediately?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867939/how-to-execute-function-immediately)

Comment: examples http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some [**stop()**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)'s :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sidebar .nav li a.animate").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
        $(this).stop(true,true)
               .animate({textIndent: e.type=='mouseenter' ? 133 : 27}, "fast")
    });
});
```

Comment: Uhm, here's the snippet with your modification:
http://carminella.it/test2.php

It's a bit better because the stop() works, but if you pass rather fast between the elements you can see that the animations always start again.. is there a way to block or retard the other animations in order to not have this weird sensation..? it's difficult to explain, just try hovering the elements on the new link :)
If it's not possible to "fix" this behavior, I'll accept this ;)

Comment: Try fiddling with the options (the two true's), the first one clear's the queue and the second one jumps to the end of the animation, so try setting false values instead and see it you can achieve what you want by doing so.